# IE8 crashes when loading website - res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Our website crashes when one of our users loads the front page in IE 8.0.6001.18702.

The page loads briefly and then IE stops loading it and shows an error message.

The URL in the address bar is changed to:

```
res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm#ourwebsite.com,http://demo.ourwebsite.com/login/
```

I've read accounts of this happening to other users of IE8 when loading sites such as facebook.com & barnesandnoble.com.

Forums such as [this](http://www.nocrash.com/ncbbs/msgs/3138.shtml) refer to possible fixes, such as:

```
unchecking the'Enable third party browser extensions' option in IE 8 advanced option
```

However, this isn't really an option for us as the site will eventually become a public facing website. We need to apply a fix to the page IE8 is trying to load.

So, does anyone know what it is about the page that IE8 is trying to load that might cause it to do this?

Comment: I should add that I have tested this on another computer, with an identical version of IE (8.0.6001.18702) and it works fine.

Comment: Out of the blue I got multiple reports on this issue for a site we are involved in (http://www.dhf.dk/) - common for all reports are IE8 + XP (but not all IE8 XP users experience it). I'm unable to repro this so it is kind of hard to dig into.

Comment: @mawtex you're loading jQuery twice, once as `/Frontend/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js` and second time as `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js` another suspicious thing is the background URL `/Renderers/ShowMedia.ashx?i=MediaArchive:/Fælles/Baggrundstapeter/DHF_2010_03.jpg` which contains fancy characters..

Comment: [res://ieframe.dll error in IE 8](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/resieframedll-error-in-ie-8/7f657540-474f-4587-b661-c3ffbb1aed06)

Answer (score 6):

I had this happening with a Drupal theme. None of the many suggestions on various threads (change IE security settings or some other advanced settings, update Java, update Flash, fiddle with registry, remove certain Windows updates, check plugins, scan for malware, completely reinstall IE8) worked for me.

In [this case](http://drupal.org/node/1323608), it turned out to be a problem with setting a background-image on a body element - changing `body` to an `html` element fixed things. It is apparently related to [loading respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/issues/27) - try putting that at the bottom.

Comment: In my case, it was a `font-size: 0` mixed with a visibility snippet triggered via respond.js.

Answer (score 5):

Try looking for Windows Error Reporting events in the affected machine's Event Viewer, specifically for iexplore.exe. That might give you a pointer for what component is getting loaded in IE that is causing the crash.  Even more precise would be to launch IE under a debugger (e.g. windbg), repro the crash and then get a call stack.  If you have a bad 3rd party add-on, it should be towards the top of the call stack. Though you said that it "isn't really an option" it will be important for you to identify a possible incompatibility and either reach out to the add-on developer, or workaround the issue on your side.

Comment: Note that IE8 is multi-process, so you will have to select "Debug child processes" if you are launching iexplore using WinDbg.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I managed to solve it by simply updating my version of jquery. I was using 1.6.1 and updated to 1.7.1 - no more crashes.

Answer (score 3):

We've solved this by replacing some nasty code in our base html file.

Before:

```
 meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge;chrome=1"
```

After:

And the solution came by replacing it with this magical line:

```
 meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same issue and it was because I was trying to manipulate elements using javascript in a div that was `overflow: scroll`, all I did was change `overflow` to `auto` and everything worked.

Hope this helps

Comment: This fixed a similar problem for me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Check the header to make sure that the doctype is going to work with Internet Explorer without it having to 'guess' how to render it.

You can also force the render engine in IE 8/9 to use the earlier IE7 renderer. This also has the benefit of removing the 'compatibility view' icon in the address bar area.

Try putting this in your .htaccess:

```
Header set X-UA-Compatible IE=EmulateIE7
```

Or, if you can write the headers:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

@mawtex you will want to do this just for IE8 as your site works fine in 7 and 9, just not 8.

More details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is a known bug in jQuery 1.6.2 that is triggered by a background image being placed on the body element.

The bug report and patch are:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9823

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/5c4a9cc001fcd803efa65ff95571c72cbdafbe69

I've also had modernizr trigger this error but since I could work around it I never chased it down.

Comment: +1 for tipping me off to the possibility that it was Modernizr-related.  Specifically for me, it was a custom build of 2.5.2 that used an outdated version of Respond.js—more info here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/332

Answer (score 1):

```
Error "res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm#"
```

In my case, cannot open some websites or after openned IE8 gave "cannot return to website error".
After some visits to MS help sites like [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/resieframedllacrerrorhtm/961b52cc-b113-4af0-b49a-a1c217c770c5) and followed all the instructioms with no avail I saw what seems to me a tip.

In one of the MS websites they say to delete old Java versions using "control panel" and "add remove programs".
I did just that but only saw one version of Java v.6u22. Then I got the idea of download the last version of Java from some days ago v.6u29 and voila... IE8 is working now and seems OK.
I'm writing this in the hope this can help others.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a background image on the body. Check this link for more informations : http://drupal.org/node/1323608

Answer (score 0):

If this seems inconsistent from machine to machine, have you made sure that some 3rd party app like virus scan isn't intercepting something?

Answer (score 0):

If the errors are caused by malware or spyware rogue extensions (especially those trying to spy on facebook account/pwd), which is perfectly possible, and this *will happen anyway* in the wild world, there is basically nothing you can do.

The best you can do is validate your site on various standard installations and browsers, including standard 3rd parties (like Adobe's flash, etc.), and add a help pages on your site to help your end user sort these kind of problems out by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Forcefully set the IE compatibility mode to IE7 or IE9 in the header section of your master page For example

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2 out of 2 occasions of reports IE8 crashing I got it fixed with removing the background-image from the body element in css.
Background-colors are no problem and also putting the same background-image on any other element(for example html) is no problem.

The crash only happened in an actual IE8 in IE8 mode. So you can't test this in IE9 compatibility mode and strangely it can indeed be 'fixed' by forcing IE8 to go into IE7 mode.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue was only in Win XP IE8.

The issue was due to CSS file. I have removed all the fonts settings from body class and it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I removed whole css under  in head, which was loading colors and images for error/highlighting messages in page.And the website is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reload the page - this brings the error message up again. Instead, start at the beginning of the URL you were looking at a second ago, and delete everything before it. Then press enter. The error won't come back for at least another little while.

I know because FanFiction.net has the same problem, and this is how I've solved it.

Comment: This does not realy answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent IE8 from going on an endless loop of refreshing and crashing it stops after two times and shows this url. There could be many issues that might be causing it to crash.

In my case an upgrade to jQuery v1.10.2 from v1.4.4 causing the issue, but it must have been mostly our code bad and was now more evident with the upgrade.

My observation was everything seems working fine on IE7/XP, IE8/Win7, IE9/Win7 and IE10/Win7 but was not working fine on IE8/XP and IE8/Server2003. The version of IE8 on Win7 and XP/Server 2003 are different. Here is the list of versions for each Operating System (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969393).

Then looked at Event viewer on Win Server 2003 and it had something like faulting module mshtml.dll, version 8.0.6001.18975 and on Win XP it was faulting module mshtml.dll, version 8.0.6001.18702 even though the browser version is same on both which is 8.0.6001.18702.

Then further searching about this mshtml.dll, it looks like Microsoft keeps updating mshtml.dll which is the HTML component of the browser through patches. So then I realised its not the browser version that is important but mshtml.dll version instead.

So I went ahead and downloaded the latest Cumulative patch for IE8 from here (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms13-059) which updated my mshtml.dll file (in system32 folder) to 8.0.6001.23515 and it started working fine , may be they fixed it some time back probably in this (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-037)

See also:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980344
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979665

But first things first always reset your browser so that you disable all plugins and rule out the possible cause by external plugins.