# Why don't my web pages open in IE8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE8 crashes when loading website - res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004428/ie8-crashes-when-loading-website-res-ieframe-dll-acr-error-htm)

When I try to open my web pages in IE8, it goes like this:

```
res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm#egtours.com,http://www.egtours.com/Eastern_Himalayas.php
```

Is this caused by problems in my webpage code or jQuery conflicts?

Comment: check this http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=45186

Answer (score 0):

Seems, your IE is getting crashed. updating your jquery version might solve your problem.

Reference:

1) [click here 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004428/ie8-crashes-when-loading-website-res-ieframe-dll-acr-error-htm)

2)[click here 2](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_xp/resieframedll-error-in-ie-8/7f657540-474f-4587-b661-c3ffbb1aed06)